Nyquist criteria along longitudinal axis
I understand that magnification of an imaging system must be so chosen so that at least 2 pixels sample the best lateral resolution (x-y) as per the Nyquist criteria. So in optical microscopy, if we are aiming for 200 nm resolution, then pixel size must be at least 100 nm.
However, I don't understand the concept of sampling the depth of field of the objective by at least two times. Can someone please give an intuitive picture? What I mean is, if the axial resolution is say 500 nm, then we need to acquire images at an interval of 250 nm along z? (1) Why we need to do this and (2) do we take an average of the two images to generate the final image?
